# Multilinear regression with `statsmodels.formula.api`

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, statsmodels

I have a dataset that I've imported from a `.csv` file into a pandas dataframe, and I'm trying to do multiple linear regression on one of the columns, as a function of two of the others. In this case `sm` is `statsmodels.formula.api`. It's giving me the error `ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key`. See image below. Does anyone know how to approach this differently?

[image: code snippet]

Comment: look at the documentation for the correct signature for the formula interface `sm.ols('wt ~ ht + age', data)`

Comment: @Josef Thank you, yep, I've got it working now. I'll update my question to include the answer shortly.